# Expand CSV records using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a CSV file named `file1.csv` like below:

```
#file1.csv
place,time,count
1,1,10
2,2,12
```

I'd like to create a new CSV file named `file2.csv` whose header is the same as above but place code is 10 times plus [1-4] and count is 1/4 (and time keeps the same value).

As a result, the number of row of `file2.csv` is 4 times larger than `file1.csv`. (I need to convert the above sample csv into below.)

```
#file2.csv
place,time,count
11,1,2.5
12,1,2.5
13,1,2.5
14,1,2.5
21,2,3
22,2,3
23,2,3
24,2,3
```

I usually use pandas (or numpy) to handle CSV file but I do not know the way to expand pandas DataFrame's records.

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("file1.csv")

new = pd.DataFrame({"time": np.repeat(df.time.values, 4)}, columns=df.columns)
new["place"] = np.concatenate([np.ones(4) * df.place[i] * 10 + np.arange(1,5) for i,_ in enumerate(df.time)])
new["count"] = np.concatenate([np.ones(4) * df["count"][i] / 4 for i,_ in enumerate(df.time)])
new.to_csv("file2.csv")
```

---

EDIT: Now it should work as intended.

Comment: Maybe my previous explanation mislead you. I edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But, there might be any other nicer way as you mentioned.